# How to draw a ellipse/oval this in WPF?

Tags: wpf, ellipse

I have two points and I want to draw a ellipse/circle to around these points.
these points' position are unfixed.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: With two points you can only assume a circle (the middle of these points to be the center of the circle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the points are unfixed , when you get two points, 
I will say take the shortest distance between them as a diameter.
You will get the mid point of the diameter as a Center.
And then you can apply Ellipse methods and properties to create a circle or an eclipse.

Comment: thanks a lot.But how can i draw the ellipse use these point and the diameter?

Comment: To make an ellipse u need four points, since the formula for ellipse is    x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1  where a and b are the length of semi-major axis ,length of semi-minor axis respectively.. But still i will suggest you a method in my next comment , try it.

Comment: For the ellipse,taking the shortest distance between them as a diameter will not work and finding the center will not work.

Comment: You have 2 points, Select one point (x1,y1) and draw a horizontal/vertical line and take second point(x2,y2) draw either a horizontal/vertical line such that two lines intersect on point(x3,y3). Now distance between the first point and intersected point will be length "a" and distance between the first point and intersected point will be length "b".

Answer (score 0):

Wpf provides a lot of `Shape` classes to draw different kinds of shapes. `Ellipse` class is one of them. You could try using that. Here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the middle of the two points, this gives you the center of the circle.

Calculate the distance between the two points, this gives the width (and height) of the circle.

Subtract half of the distance from the center.X and half of the distance of center.Y, this gives the top left corner of the circle.

```
<Ellipse Canvas.Top="topLeft.Y"
         Canvas.Left="topLeft.X" 
         Width="distance" 
         Height="distance"/>
```

Note: the values are pseudo values; you need to replace them with the actual values.

Comment: tks.but i want to draw a oval,not round

Comment: @user1140125 - How do you want an oval to be defined by two points?